# Как поменять апсейл у товаров в WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

как изменить апсейл товаров если их больше 1000. Что можно сделать чтобы быстро все поменять?
P.S. Апсейл должен быть одинаковый у всех

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите функцию `woocommerce_upsell_display` в ней есть фильтр `woocommerce_upsell_display_args`. Ваш код должен быть примерно такой:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_upsell_display_args', function( $args ) {
    $args['post__in'] = [ 10, 20, 30 ]; // ID товаров
} );
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как указать все товары?

Comment: Что значит все товары? В целом читайте https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query все параметры оттуда можете использовать. Вам скорее всего нужен posts_per_page параметр